# Stream is closed when wildfly run as service

Tags: java, wildfly-10

I am using java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to execute a python program. It all works well when I upload it to a standalone wildfly 10.1 (I run this wildfly on demand by terminal), but it goes wrong when I upload this WAR file to a wildfly that is ran as a service

```
private Process p = null;
private BufferedWriter output;

p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pythonPath + " " + pythonAppPath);
output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));

// checking pid of running process
System.out.println("1. " + checkPID("python")); 

Thread.sleep(2000);

// checking pid of running process
System.out.println("2. " + checkPID("python")); 

output.write(connectCmd);
output.flush();

// checking pid of running process
System.out.println("3. " + checkPID("python"));
```

checkPID mehod

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pidof " + appName);
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

return stdInput.readLine();
```

This is the error message from the server log

```
1. 2232
2. null
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
at com.sisu.thebot.controller.wa.someBot.goOffline(someBot.java:104)
at com.sisu.thebot.controller.wa.someBot.runTheBot(someBot.java:35)
at com.sisu.thebot.controller.quartz.Jobs.execute(Jobs.java:31)
at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
3. null
```

`System.out.println` 1 result is "1. [some PID] but `System.out.println` 2 result is "2. null". So i assume the trouble was `Thread.sleep` can't be used on wildfly as service, because it kill the process ? But why ? Or maybe any other method that i can try to wait the process to finish before give the process a command ?

Once again this error only happens when wildfly is ran as a service, it works well when I run wildfly manually from the terminal. I use springboot 2.0.4 and quartzscheduler as well.

Comment: What's the implementation of `checkPID` ?

Comment: Also, it seems likely that the process is successfully invoked but exits in error less than 2 seconds afterward. I'd suspect insufficient permissions due to running the wildfly as another user than the one who runs your standalones.

Comment: checkPID is just checking PID of Process p when and return int value of PID if the process running and null if the process is not running. I give it 2 second delay to finish the process before entering the command

Comment: I'm still pretty sure the python script is correctly called but fails itself in less than two seconds. Can you check its output or somehow debug it? Maybe use pdb? e.g. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pythonPath + " -m pdb " + pythonAppPath)`. Not sure how well this will behave, I have no experience with pdb

Comment: If it's supposed to write on `stdout` or `stderr` (on the console when called from the shell), at least check your `p.getInputStream()` and `p.getErrorStream()` for an error.

Comment: same with me i don't have any experience on pdb. After i try to enter the command with pdb on terminal (not on coding) i get pdb prompt . . so what i have to do with it . . 

The error log was clear there IOException : stream closed

Comment: The `IOException : stream closed` is a Java error that happens because you try to write things for your process but it has already exited, so it's OutputStream is closed. All your symptoms point to the python process exiting before 2 seconds, but none tell us why.

Comment: yes you're right the process was killed after Thread.sleep() by looking at the PID is null. Is there any probability if Thread.sleep() kill the process because if i remove Thread.sleep() there is no IOException error (well the python program of course not properly running because it need certain time to load)

Comment: Doesn't the python script require some input and exit if it hasn't any? Because that might explain why it quits if you only provide it with input two seconds after it has started. The `Thread.sleep` only applies to your current thread, not to the python process you started, so when you add the `Thread.sleep` it has two seconds to run without having any input.

Comment: My python is a bit rusty but it could help if you posted your python script's code too.

Comment: its yowsup2 this is the github https://github.com/tgalal/yowsup.
And yowsup by default (in terminal) will wait for input and not exit until i press ctrl+c 

i run yowsup-cli (about 300 lines of code) from java and add bufferedwriter to give it command

Comment: It's possible that `yowsup-cli` would detect whether it's executed interactively or not and if not fail when it has no input to parse. That said, I don't see why this would behave differently between your standalone wildfly and the service one. Have you been able to check the process' stdout and stderr through the `Process.getInputStream / getErrorStream`, maybe enabling the `-d` flag for debug output first ? It looks like yowsup-cli should output some logs even when it fails.

Comment: Yes . . that was something i miss. yowsup need to store cache on user home folder and the user which run wildfly as service doesn't have home folder. So after i create home folder for the usereverything runs fine. . . Thanks @Aaron

Comment: You're welcome, glad you could progress !